# assign lastinsertid to a variable

Tags: php, pdo, lastinsertid

I am basically a new programmer, with some Oracle experience from years gone by.  I have a form that collects household and member information (which also has a dropdown with a database connection that connects to the database to retrieve a listbox of branches).

On the POST, it saves the information to the household and member tables in the database.  The household is a parent table, so the record must be created first.  I need to then retrieve the household.id ( a MySql auto increment field) to save to the member table, to associate the two.

On execution of the insert to the household table, it works fine.  I printed the autoincrement field to check.

```
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
     $stmt->execute();
     print("lastinsertid is really = \n");
  //   $lastid->$dbh->lastInsertId();
     print $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

But I need to use it in the next statement so need to store it.  When I do that (just change what is commented out), I get errors.

```
     $dbh->beginTransaction();
     $stmt->execute();
     print("lastinsertid is really = \n");
     $lastid->$dbh->lastInsertId();
  //   print $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

Errors:

> PHP Notice: Undefined variable: lastid in C:\Users\Desktop\OECC\form with lastinsertid works.php on line 165
>   PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Desktop\OECC\form with lastinsertid works.php on line 165
>   PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function lastInsertId() on null in C:\Users\Desktop\OECC\form with lastinsertid works.php on line 165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lastid = $dbh->lastInsertId()`

You're using `->` instead of `=`